# Removing and adding spaces before and after the parenthesis special character by using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to check for punctuation rule of parenthesis in text. My aim is to achieve the following:

1. Space before open parenthesis and after closed parenthesis
2. No space after open parenthesis and before parenthesis

If text already follows above conditions then ignore either adding or removing spaces.

I tried following code which finds "( " and replaces it with " (" i.e. space before opening parenthesis. When I run this, PowerPoint stops responding.

Though there are many similar questions, I couldn't find a solution which uses VBA.

```
Sub ReplaceSpaces()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim shpText As TextRange

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            Set shpText = shp.TextFrame.TextRange

            Do While InStr(shpText.Text, "(") > 0
                shpText.Replace FindWhat:="( ", ReplaceWhat:=" ("
                shpText.Replace FindWhat:=" )", ReplaceWhat:=") "
            Loop

        End If
    Next shp
Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: See if adding `DoEvents` before the `Loop` token makes PPT more responsive.

Comment: The problem with the code is that it introduces an infinite loop. The `Do While ... ` condition will always be true if there is a parenthesis, whether or not there is a space after it. So, even when you replace "(" with "( ", the function call to `InStr(shpText.Text, "(") > 0` will return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not use regex as that can be complicated if you need to support MAC.
First it ensures that ( has a space before and ) a space after.
Then it removes excess spaces before ( and after ).
Finally any space after ( or before ) is removed.

```
Sub ReplaceSpaces()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim shpText As TextRange


For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            Set shpText = shp.TextFrame.TextRange

            shpText.Replace FindWhat:="(", ReplaceWhat:=" ("
            shpText.Replace FindWhat:=")", ReplaceWhat:=") "
            Do While InStr(shpText.Text, "  (") > 0
                shpText.Replace FindWhat:="  (", ReplaceWhat:=" ("
            Loop
            Do While InStr(shpText.Text, "( ") > 0
                shpText.Replace FindWhat:="( ", ReplaceWhat:="("
            Loop
            Do While InStr(shpText.Text, ")  ") > 0
                shpText.Replace FindWhat:=")  ", ReplaceWhat:=") "
            Loop
            Do While InStr(shpText.Text, " )") > 0
                shpText.Replace FindWhat:=" )", ReplaceWhat:=")"
            Loop

        End If
   Next shp
 Next sld
 End Sub
```

Comment: Now I will customize this to include different punctuation rules. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a comment under your main post detailing *why* your code didn't work. The below code uses a regular expression to replace all opening parenthesis without a trailing space to an opening parenthesis with a trailing space.

Write back if you need additional help.

```
Function FindAndReplace(testString As String, oSource As TextRange)
    Dim oReg As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

    'Set oSource = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange

    Set oReg = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

    With oReg
        .Global = True
        .Multiline = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(\()([^\s]+?)"  'Checks for an opening parenthesis with no following space
    End With

    If oReg.Test(testString) Then
        oSource.Text = oReg.Replace(testString, "$1 $2")
    End If
End Function

Sub ReplaceSpaces()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim shpText As TextRange


    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                Set shpText = shp.TextFrame.TextRange

                FindAndReplace shpText.Text, shpText

            End If
       Next shp
     Next sld
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with the regular expression yet and I need to study on "VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp" used. What does "$1 $2" mean? This will be helpful in future.